# Probability of Various Combinations of Weather

Tags: probability

There's a 10% chance it will rain today. There's a 15% chance it will snow today.

What percentage chance is it that it will:

- Both rain and snow (it can both rain and snow at the same time)?
- Neither rain nor snow?
  -

Raining and snowing are independent of each other.

EDIT: (ADDED)

- Rain or snow but not both?

Comment: We are probably invited to assume independence, That is an unreasonable assumption.

Comment: or as in xor, or exclusive or.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Short explanation:

Let $A$ : probability of **snow** ($A=0.15$); 
Let $B$ : probability of **rain** ($B=0.10$);

There are $4$ possible events:

**1)** No snow, no rain:  $P_1 = (1-A)(1-B) = 0.85\cdot 0.90 = 0.765$; 
**2)** Snow, but no rain:  $P_2 = A(1-B) = 0.15\cdot 0.90 = 0.135$; 
**3)** No snow, but rain:  $P_3 = (1-A)B = 0.85\cdot 0.10 = 0.085$; 
**4)** Snow with rain:  $P_4 = AB = 0.15\cdot 0.10 = 0.015$.

Note that $P_1+P_2+P_3+P_4=1$.

---

- Both rain and snow: $0.015 \ \ (1.5\%)$;
- Neither rain nor snow: $0.765 \ \ (76.5\%);$
- Either raining or snowing: $0.135+0.085 = 0.22 \ \ (22\%)$.

---

Illustration ([Euler diagram](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Euler_diagram)):

[image]

---

Other illustration:

[image]

Answer (score 7):

Assuming (unreasonably $\dagger$) that "raining" $R$ and "snowing" $S$ are *independent events*,

- the probability of (rain and snow) = $$P(R \cap S) = P(R)\times P(S) = (0.1)\times(0.15) = 0.015 = 1.5\%$$
- The probability that it does not rain and it does not snow = $$P(\bar{R}\cap \bar S) = (1 - 0.1)\times (1 - 0.15) = (0.9)\times(0.85) = 0.765 = 76.5\%$$

---

$(\dagger)$ As a resident of Wisconsin, I know all too well that rain and snow are not, in reality, independent events. In "early spring" and "later fall" it is very likely that rain in the day turns to snow in the evening, so when one event happens it is very likely the other event will happen too. In short rain and snow, in the real world, are hardly independent! But for the purpose of this assignment, if it is to be answerable given the little information we have, we have assumed independence!

Comment: extra points for the nice notation, this was just a thought experiment, and I was wondering if I was doing it correctly. Thanks!

Comment: You're welcome! ;-) Hope you have a rain-and-snow-free day!

Comment: @amWhy: I remember the rain and snow and black ice from NJ! +1

Comment: how about if it will either rain or snow, but not both?

Answer (score 0):

A variant of this question got deleted as a duplicate of this one, so I'm pasting a variant of my answer to that one here:

$$
\begin{align}
\Pr(\text{rain or snow (or both)}) & = 1 - \Pr(\text{neither rain nor snow}) \\[10pt]
& = 1 - \Pr(\text{not rain AND not snow}) \\[10pt]
& = 1 - \Pr(\text{not rain})\cdot\Pr(\text{ not snow}).
\end{align}
$$
You need independent events with the word "and" between them.  Then you can just multiply probabilities.

Now, then:
$$
\Pr(\text{rain or snow but not both}) + \Pr(\text{both}) = \Pr(\text{rain or snow or both}),
$$
and that last probability was found above.  The probability $\Pr(\text{both})$ can be found simply by multiplying.

Comment: The OP posted a new question (the one you're answering here) but this time clarifying exclusive or...maybe you want to post this answer there. :-)