# Probability that it is raining or snowing but not both?

Tags: probability

It can either rain, or snow, or do both, or neither. There is a $15\%$ chance that it is snowing right now. There is a $10\%$ chance that it is raining right now. Each is independent of the other. What is the chance that it is either raining or snowing right now, but not both?

Comment: Euler diagram (http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Euler_diagram) is helpful here.

Comment: I posted my answer to this under one of your earlier questions.  I suspect this question may be closed as a "duplicate" of that earlier one.

Comment: Please don't post the same question twice, it really doesn't help.

Answer (score 2):

Short explanation:

Let $A$ : probability of **snow** ($A=0.15$); 
Let $B$ : probability of **rain** ($B=0.10$);

There are $4$ possible events:

**1)** No snow, no rain:  $P_1 = (1-A)(1-B) = 0.85\cdot 0.90 = 0.765$; 
**2)** Snow, but no rain:  $P_2 = A(1-B) = 0.15\cdot 0.90 = 0.135$; 
**3)** No snow, but rain:  $P_3 = (1-A)B = 0.85\cdot 0.10 = 0.085$; 
**4)** Snow with rain:  $P_4 = AB = 0.15\cdot 0.10 = 0.015$.

Event **either raining or snowing** has probability $P_2 + P_3 = A(1-B)+B(1-A) = 0.135+0.085 = 0.22$.

---

Note that $P_2+P_4 = A$, $\ \ \ $ $P_3+P_4 = B$.

---

Illustration:

[image]

---

(I copied this answer (with modification) here :  [Probability of Various Combinations of Weather](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/429275/probability-of-various-combinations-of-weather), because actual question marked as duplicated).